# Vertically align text with image

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align some text in the middle of an image, and I've tried a few different ways of vertical-align, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Currently, layout looks so:
[image: Current layout]

and the HTML/CSS used for this is:

```
<p id="searchresults">Search Results</p>

        <ul id="posted_results">
            <?php
                foreach($search_result['movies'] as $sr){
                    echo '<li class="search_item"><a href="/ug10/cs10aer/screening/movie.php?title=' . $sr['title'] . '" alt="' . $sr['title'] . ' (' . $sr['year'] . ')"><img src="' . $sr['posters']['thumbnail'] . '" title="' . $sr['title'] . ' poster" alt="' . $sr['title'] . ' poster" /></a><a href="/ug10/cs10aer/screening/movie.php?title=' . $sr['title'] . '" alt="' . $sr['title'] . ' (' . $sr['year'] . ')">' . $sr['title'] . ' (' . $sr['year'] . ')</a></li>';
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
```

[image: Current CSS]

**UPDATE**
Just for further guidance, I'm wanting to get the text for each list object to display thus:
[image: Wanted layout]

**UPDATE 2**
As requested, here's the HTML code as seen by Firefox:

```
<div id="content">

        <p id="searchresults">Search Results</p>

        <ul id="posted_results">
            <li class="search_item"><a href="/ug10/cs10aer/screening/movie.php?title=Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith 3D" alt="Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith 3D (2005)"><img src="http://content8.flixster.com/movie/10/94/47/10944718_mob.jpg" title="Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith 3D poster" alt="Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith 3D poster" /></a><a href="/ug10/cs10aer/screening/movie.php?title=Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith 3D" alt="Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith 3D (2005)">Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith 3D (2005)</a></li>
            <li class="search_item"><a href="/ug10/cs10aer/screening/movie.php?title=Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones 3D" alt="Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones 3D (2002)"><img src="http://content7.flixster.com/movie/10/94/47/10944721_mob.jpg" title="Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones 3D poster" alt="Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones 3D poster" /></a><a href="/ug10/cs10aer/screening/movie.php?title=Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones 3D" alt="Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones 3D (2002)">Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones 3D (2002)</a></li>
            <li class="search_item"><a href="/ug10/cs10aer/screening/movie.php?title=Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope" alt="Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope (1977)"><img src="http://content9.flixster.com/movie/10/94/47/10944715_mob.jpg" title="Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope poster" alt="Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope poster" /></a><a href="/ug10/cs10aer/screening/movie.php?title=Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope" alt="Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope (1977)">Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope (1977)</a></li>
            <li class="search_item"><a href="/ug10/cs10aer/screening/movie.php?title=Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi" alt="Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi (1983)"><img src="http://content7.flixster.com/movie/10/94/47/10944709_mob.jpg" title="Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi poster" alt="Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi poster" /></a><a href="/ug10/cs10aer/screening/movie.php?title=Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi" alt="Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi (1983)">Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi (1983)</a></li>
        </ul>


    </div>
```

Comment: how you want ?? could you show image

Comment: could you provide us with a link?

Comment: I've just added an image at the bottom of the post showing what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Please provide the HTML, not the php code. We need to see what the browser sees, not what the server sees.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert I've added the HTML code at the bottom of the post. The contents of the ul, including the li, img, href, title and alt tags are all being generated dynamically from the PHP foreach from $search_results array.

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your question that you have even attempted to use vertical alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the float from the image and use vertical-align:

```
.search_item img {
    vertical-align: middle;  
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tNhyj/

Answer (score 0):

if the image is always the same height + descriptions lenght is always gonna be similar, you could hack it with line-height or/and margin-top, or using vertical-align on image eample using vertical-align can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13780959/1134615

simple fiddle using line height:

http://jsfiddle.net/BrFga/

html

```
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src=""/>       
            <p>Sample text</p>
    </li>
    </ul>​
```

css

```
ul {
    height: 120px;
    width: 600px;
    outline: red 1px solid; 
}

img {
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
}

p {
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 120px;
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

You may add vertical-align:middle to the image.

```
li img {
 vertical-align:middle;
padding-right:10px;    
}
```

Check this jsfiddle to see if it is what you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/3ETDj/

For me it is working in Firefox, IE8, Chrome and Opera.